# QProcess does not emit finished signal

Tags: qt, qml

I try to read out the output of a command executed in `QProcess`. I don't get the connection working between `QProcess`'s finished signal and a finished handler.
I tried several different ways of connecting to `QProcess` finished signal but no luck so far. I know that the process executes because it prints the output in the GUI's console and that the process finishes because it passes the `waitForFinished` method from sequential API.

Why does my code not hit `onFinish` or `onFinishNoPams`?

header:

```
class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void read();
public slots:
    void onFinish(int exitCode , QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
    void onFinishNoPams();

private:
    QProcess *m_process;

};
```

cpp:

```
Test::Test(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
{}
void Test::read(){
    m_process=new QProcess(this);

    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(onFinishNoPams()));

    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(onFinish(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));

    connect(m_process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished),
        [=](int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
    qDebug() << "not reached";
    });

    connect(m_process, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), this,&Test::onFinish);

    QString program = "lsusb";
    QStringList arguments;
    m_process->execute(program,arguments);
    m_process->waitForFinished();
    qDebug() << "reached";
    return;
}

void Test::onFinish(int exitCode , QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus){
    qDebug() << "not reached";
}

void Test::onFinishNoPams(){
    qDebug() << "not reached";
    QByteArray out=m_process->readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

qml:

```
import test 1.0

Window {    
    Test{
        id:test
        Component.onCompleted: test.read()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QProcess::execute()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute) is a static method that starts the external process and waits for its completion in a blocking way. It has nothing to do with your m_process variable. What you want to use is [QProcess::start()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start).